# how to sort data on data band in fast report using script

Tags: c#, fastreport

I want to sort data band after load data in report file and show report.
but i want to sort with specific parameter and sort data on this parameter.

i use group header for grouping on ID and group footer and data band.

now, What should I do?

help me please.

Comment: where is your effort?

Comment: Please edit your question and include what have you done and tried.

Comment: i want to sort data after load report programmatically, can you help me?